# How to use the global.php/local.php configs in the getConfig() of a module in a Zend Framework 2 application?

Tags: configuration, zend-framework2, config, configuration-files

In a ZF2 application I have some cofigs, that: 1. need to be different dependening on the environment; 2. are specific for a concrete module. I'm curently using it like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15825220/2019043) described:

**global.php & local.php**

```
return array(
    ...
    'modules' => array(
        'Cache' => array(
            'ttl' => 1, // 1 second
        )
    )
    ...
);
```

**Module class**

```
Module {
    ...
    public function getServiceConfig() {
        try {
            return array (
                'factories' => array(
                    'Zend\Cache\Adapter\MemcachedOptions' => function ($serviceManager) {
                        return new MemcachedOptions(array(
                            'ttl'           => $this->getConfig()['modules']['Cache']['ttl'],
                            ...
                        ));
                    },
                    ...
                )
            );
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

It's working fine, but I believe, that the module specific settings should be accessed over one central place in the module -- the `getConfig()` method of the `Module` class. Like this:

```
class Module {

    public function getConfig() {
        $moduleConfig = include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
        $application = $this->getApplicationSomehow(); // <-- how?
        $applicationModuleConfig = $application->getConfig()['modules'][__NAMESPACE__];
        $config = array_merge($moduleConfig, $applicationModuleConfig);
        return $config;
    }
    ...
    public function getServiceConfig() {
        try {
            return array (
                'factories' => array(
                    'Zend\Cache\Adapter\MemcachedOptions' => function ($serviceManager) {
                        return new MemcachedOptions(array(
                            'ttl'            => $serviceManager->get('Config')['modules']['Cache']['ttl'],
                            ...
                        ));
                    },
                    ...
                )
            );
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem is, that I don't get, how to access the global.php/local.php configs in the `getConfig()` of a module. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You're not supposed to access other Modules setting in your `Module#getConfig()`. If you rely on other configuration, that CAN ONLY BE for service purposes. Ergo you'd rely on `Module#getServiceConfig()` and inside the factories you do have access to the `ServiceManager`and access your configs with `$serviceManager->get('config');`.* (see Sam's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832546/how-to-use-the-global-php-local-php-configs-in-the-getconfig-of-a-module-in-a/15833073#comment22632878_15833073))

The loading order of the configs is by default:

1. `/config/application.config.php`, that is the initial config file; not for module configs; here is the filename pattern for the config files to load defined (`'config_glob_paths' => array('config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php')`).
2. `{ModuleNamespace}\Module#getConfig()` (e.g. `Cache\Module#getConfig()`), that by convention should load its `/module/{ModuleNamespace}/config/module.config.php`;
3. `/config/autoload/global.php`, that should not contain any module specific configs (see below);
4. `/config/autoload/local.php`, that contains *environment specific* settings also should not contain any module specific configs (see below); it should not versioned/deployed;
5. `/config/autoload/{ModuleNamespaceLowerCased}.local.php` (e.g. `cache.local.php`), that contains only the *module AND environment specific* settings and should not be versioned/;

For the `Cache` module above there can be following config files:

- `/module/Cache/config/module.config.php` -- a complete set of module configs; loaded by `Cache\Module#getConfig()`
- `/module/Cache/config/cache.local.php.dist` -- an example for `/config/autoload/cache.local.php`
- `/config/autoload/cache.local.php` -- environment specific module configs

The setting `ttl` can be accessed from any place, where one has access to the Service Locator. For example in factory methods of `Cache\Module#getServiceConfig()`

```
class Module {

    public function getConfig() {
        $moduleConfig = include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
        $application = $this->getApplicationSomehow(); // <-- how?
        $applicationModuleConfig = $application->getConfig()['modules'][__NAMESPACE__];
        $config = array_merge($moduleConfig, $applicationModuleConfig);
        return $config;
    }
    ...
    public function getServiceConfig() {
        try {
            return array (
                'factories' => array(
                    'Zend\Cache\Adapter\MemcachedOptions' => function ($serviceManager) {
                        return new MemcachedOptions(array(
                            'ttl'            => $serviceManager->get('Config')['ttl'],
                            ...
                        ));
                    },
                    ...
                )
            );
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

For futher information about how configs are managed in ZF2 see Sam's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15833073/2019043) and [blog article](http://samminds.com/2013/04/understanding-zf2-configuration/).

Comment: Why u did not accept @sam answer as valid answer to your question?

Comment: It's a very good theoretical article (+1 for it), but it didn't give me directly the answer to my question. Anyway it helped me to understand, how configs work, and to find an answer. I posted it here and accepted / marked as "valid answer".

Answer (score 17):

Every single configuration of every single loaded Module will be merged into one single config. Namely this would be:

```
$serviceManager->get('config');
```

The reason behind `(global|local).config.php` is merely for usage purpose. Global configuration files should always be **deployed**.  Local configuration files however should only be deployed as distributionables, alias `local.config.php.dist`.

Distributionals will not be loaded, no matter where they are places. However common notion of ZF2 is to copy the distributionables into the `/config/autoload`-directory of the ZF2 Application and rename them to `local.config.php`

**One example:**

```
// YourModule/config/module.config.php
return array(
    'key' => 1337
);

// YourModule/config/local.yourmodule.php.dist
return array(
    'key' => 7331
);
```

Now when you publish / deploy your application, only `module.config.php` will be used. If someone wants to change the configuration of your Module, they would **never** touch `module.config.php`, as this file would constantly be overwritten when your module will be updated.

However what people can do is to copy:

```
YourModule/config/local.yourmodule.php.dist
to
/config/autoload/local.yourmodule.php
```

And change the config values inside this local configuration.

**To understand:**

- You should always configure your module as best as possible for a LIVE-Scenario.
- If you have environment-specific needs, overwrite this config using a local-config
- local configs are never deployed automatically, this is a manual task needing to be done from inside the environment itself

Hope this got a little more clear

**Ultimately:**

- configure your module for a LIVE-Scenario
- On your development machine create a `/config/autoload/mymodule.local.php` and overwrite your `ttl` with it's development value

**LoadOrder:**

The last interesting part, which i have completely forgotten about, would be the load order of the configuration files. As all files are merged, this is important to note!

- First to load is `/config/application.config.php`
- Second to load would be each Modules `/modules/{module}/config/module.config.php` *
- Last but not least the autoloadable files will be loaded `/config/autoload/{filename}.php`

**asterix** It is actually **NOT** `module.config.php` which is called, but rather the `Module`-classes configuration functions. Mainly these are:

- `getConfig()`
- `getServiceConfig()`
- `getViewHelperConfig()`
- ultimately everything under [`Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\{feature}ProviderInterface`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/tree/master/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Feature)

If i understand [this part of the `ConfigListener`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ConfigListener.php#L119-L166) correctly, then `getConfig()` will be called first and all of the specialiced `{feature}ProviderInterfaces` will overwrite the data of `getConfig()`, but don't take this for granted, it would need a check!

Comment: OK, I think, I got the logic. `local.%module%.php.dist` (an example for `local.%module%.php`) and `module.config.php` (default settings) in `/module/Cache/config` and `local.%module%.php` (real settings for the current environment) in `/config/autoload`. `local.%module%.php` files are merged "automatically" (magic?) to the `/config/autoload/local.php` and has a higher prioroty than `module.config.php`. 1. Do I understand this right? 2. What about the keys? If the `local.%module%.php` files are directly merged to `local.php`, how are conflicts avoided? 3. How can/should I access the settings?

Comment: At Sam: Thank you very much for your detailed answer and the update. Sorry, I still cannot understand, how to load the `/autoload/local.{modulename}.php` files. I've created `/autoload/local.cache.php` for my module `Cache`, but it is not loaded. Can you please post an elementary example, how you would set the setting `mysetting`(in all possible relevant files in the module and application config folder) for a module `MyModule` and how you would access this setting from your module class?

Comment: [@Sam](http://stackoverflow.com/users/958642/sam) To "If i understand [this part of the `ConfigListener`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ConfigListener.php#L119-L166) correctly [...]": I've just debugged a module simply setting a breakpoint into each of its config methods (this module implements only three config interfaces). The loading order is: `getAutoloaderConfig()`, `getConfig()`, `getServiceConfig()`.

Comment: @automatix I know, just today i've blogged about my findings from here;) http://samminds.com/2013/04/understanding-zf2-configuration/

Comment: **How do you call the settings?** I'm currently doing this with `$mySetting = $this->getConfig()['mySetting']` and it cannot work, since the `getConfig()` just returns the configs from `{module root directory} . '/config/module.config.php'`.

Comment: I feel like you gotta provide ALL your code on github or so. What's `$this->getConfig()`? The global configuration will be fetched from the ServiceManager (i.e. inside a controller via `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');` or iirc what you need would be `$serviceManager->get('config')`

Comment: I just wanted to understand, how to use settings in `MyModule#getConfig()` (and other places, where I cannot access the ServiceLocator). Yes, I can access the settings over `$serviceManager->get('Config')['myConfig']`. But I don't have the access to the ServiceLocator from everywhere. E.g. from `MyModule#getConfig()` or a table mapper class or so.

Comment: You're not supposed to access other Modules setting in your `Module#getConfig()`. If you rely on other configuration, that CAN ONLY BE for service purposes. Ergo you'd rely on `Module#getServiceConfig()` and inside the factories you do have access to the `ServiceManager`